# How to edit transactional e-mail (order_new) to add my module specific layout handle

Tags: layout, module, email, transactional

I'd like to edit order_new.html template to include layout handle to my own module layout. I'm new to magento, so I'd be pleased to get accurate instructions which files I have to create/edit. In order_new.html I have a line:

```
{{layout handle="gc_referer_admin_email"}}
```

My module is in located in app/code/local/GC/Referer

I tried many solutions from Internet for hours, but maybe I'm doing something wrong :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a module then you have to have a layout file for it.
this is done by adding in the `config.xml` file this inside the `<frontend>` tag:

```
   <layout>
        <updates>
            <{{namespace}}_{{module}}>
                <file>{{namespace}}_{{module}}.xml</file>
            </{{namespace}}_{{module}}>
        </updates>
    </layout>
```

Then create the file `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/{{namespace}}_{{module}}.xml` that contains this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <gc_referer_admin_email><!-- the layout handle you want to use in your email -->
        <!-- all blocks go here -->
        <block type="type/here" template="path/to/template.phtml" name="some.name" as="some.name" />
         //....
    </gc_referer_admin_email>
</layout>
```

From this point on, everything should work the same as adding blocks in the frontend.

One more thing.
If your e-mail will be sent from backend and frontend and you want it to look the same for both your code from the e-mail should be

```
{{layout handle="gc_referer_admin_email" _area="frontend"}}
```

If you want them different you don't need the `_area` attribute but you have to do the same thing as described above for the `adminhtml` tag in config.xml and the theme for the admin side.

Comment: Thank you, it works! Probably the problem was that I user type="core/text_list" instead of "core/template", but your solution helped me understand which files are necessary to do this (I had different files in various locations, because I didn't know which was the proper one).